# weak solution of viscous Burgers equation with non-homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I was wondering if anybody knows (and can give me a reference, please) if the PDE below has a unique weak solution. I can only find the result if we consider homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, but not for non-homogeneous as I need.

Many thanks!

$$ \partial_t \rho(t,u)  = \partial_u^2\rho(t,u)-E\partial_u f(\rho(t,u))\\
\rho(t,0) = \alpha\; \rho(t,1) = \beta, \quad 0\leq t\leq T,\\
\rho(0,u) = \rho_0(u)\; \quad 0\leq u \leq 1 $$
with $f(x)=x(1-x)$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $E$ constants;

Answer (score 1):

Try to substract $g(x)=\alpha-x(\alpha-\beta)$. Now the dirichlet conditions of the new unknown $h=\rho-g$ are homogeneous. The new problem is 
$$
\partial_t h=\partial_u^2h-E\partial_u f(h)+F(g).
$$ 
with initial data $h_0=\rho_0-g$.
Now I think that the usual theory applies straightforwardly.